# how to add icon in navbar odoo? after "Conversations" icon

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

Searched for it, as a result there is a file **systray.xml** in that three templates are there. that is all i found but when i try to add anything just like that file, it doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this, what needs to be done is first create a template in an XML file, then render it using javascript widget.

XML file

```
<templates>
    <t t-name="Icon">
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="Icon" href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </t>
</templates>
```

JS file

```
odoo.define('your_module_name.icons', function (require) {
    var SystrayMenu = require('web.SystrayMenu');
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');

    // Appends Icon template in system tray (navbar)
    var IconMenu = Widget.extend({
        template:'Icon',
    });
SystrayMenu.Items.push(IconMenu);
});
```

This will do the work.